# Angular code stops working when it's moved to a template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, so the documentation is a bit of a bear. When I created the following code, and it worked, I thought I was in a good place.

```
<div ng-controller="postListController">
    {{someDataStuff}} <!-- this always works -->
    <div ng-repeat="post in data">
            <b>{{post.title}}</b> <!-- This sometimes works -->
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this Javascript in Angular (a snippet, really)

```
var listController = app.controller('postListController', function postListController($scope) {
    $scope.someDataStuff = 'hey there.';
    $scope.data = new Object(null);
    $.get('get.php',function(data) {
        $scope.data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
});
```

`someDataStuff` printed out, and Angular looped happily through the `post.titles`. Then I tried moving this stuff, verbatim, to a template file and loading it appropriately...

```
app.directive('ngPostList', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'postlist.html'
    }
});
```

This part... only sorta worked. While I was still getting data (returned it in console.log), and I was still getting `someDataStuff` to come back, it was no actually looping through the data.

[image: demonstration -- first works, second doesn't]

Is there something in app.directive I'm missing to make it pass data on to the template I'm now using?

[image: more source code]

Comment: Do not use `$.get`, instead use angular ajax utility with `$http` otherwise you wont see the bindings updated unless  digest cycle is invoked manually. Please create a demo to showcase the issue.

Comment: Yikes, I really should never have taken that "as much or as little as you need" thing on the Angular homepage so seriously. :/ Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: This seems like a good place to ask, where do I post an example that requires multiple HTML sources? It works fine with just one, but that's sorta counterintuitive to Angular, or so I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template should also take the controller, otherwise it is outside the scope and you are one level further down and you would have to call $parent.post.title etc... to reach the proper parent scope with the data.

try:

app.directive('ngPostList', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        Controller: 'postListController',
        templateUrl: 'postlist.html'
    }
});

Overall, pick up one of the Chrome extensions to debug Angular, like [ng-inspector](http://ng-inspector.org/), so you can see what scope has what data and it makes your life a lot easier to debug this kind of things.
Angular issues are 95% of the time issues with scope not being what your think it is.

Comment: I added this and swapped `$.get` for `$http` with little luck. Then on the Angular site I saw this: "You do not currently have the ability to access scope variables from the templateUrl function, since the template is requested before the scope is initialized." https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
**Edit1:** ...so maybe I should just take this stuff **out** of the scope? It wouldn't hurt me, I don't think.
**Edit2:** ...yes it would, I have no idea how to access things out-of-scope.

Comment: Things worked, I just made the mistake of modifying the secret sauce in the included template that was making it work successfully before. Wouldn't you know it, fixing the code in there made it work... after pretty much after I followed every suggestion on this page. :)

Comment: or, it didn't work. Came back from a day or two off and it no longer... functions... oh well. I'm gonna run anguless